# The formula for partial flow of Box Culvert

Tags: civil-engineering

Refer to [this document](https://www.concretepipe.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/DD_17.pdf), and particular to Figure 2:

[image]

I wonder what is the formula that governs the box culvert partial flow with respect to full flow? In other words, base on what formula the above graph is generated?

The [formula for pipe partial flow](https://www.cedengineering.com/userfiles/Partially%20Full%20Pipe%20Flow%20Calculations.pdf) is as thus:

[image]

So essentially I'm trying to find the analogous formula for pipe culvert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

The formula for hydraulic radius, velocity and flow remains the same. But what is important to note is the wetted perimeter, $P$.

When the flow is partial flow,

$P=2h+b$

When the flow is full flow,

$P=2h+2b$.

(because now the top part of the box is also "wetted").

This explains why the "strange" behavior how when $D:RISE$ approaches $1$, $\frac{Q}{Q_f}$ can go way beyond $1$, and when $D:RISE=1$, $\frac{Q}{Q_f}$ goes back to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Page 2 of the DD_17.pdf document that you linked tells you the answer in the first paragraph.

Manning's equation is what is used. There are different formulas used to solve for the hydraulic radius R for different shape culverts.

This is a fundamental topic for hydraulic engineering can I suggest that you find a text book on this topic? It will offer much more in depth background information than can be offered in this setting.

Comment: It doesn't explain how can the Q/Qf way more than 1, when D:RISE ratio approaches 1.

Comment: Well that wasn't part of your original question, and I think you might be able to find that answer by digging into some reference texts.